# How to do Pairing in Hive?

Tags: mysql, sql, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

1. Firstly we create a hive table by loading following csv file

> ```
> $cat data.csv
>
> ID,City,Zip,Flag
> 1,A,95126,0
> 2,A,95126,1
> 3,A,95126,1
> 4,B,95124,0
> 5,B,95124,1
> 6,C,95124,0
> 7,C,95127,1
> 8,C,95127,0
> 9,C,95127,1
> ```

(a) where "ID" above is a primary key (unique),

(b) for each "City" and "Zip" combination, there is one ID in max with Flag=0; while it can contain multiple IDs with Flag=1 for each "City" and "Zip" combination.

(c) Flag can be 0 or 1

2. Load the csv file above to a hive table

> ```
> create table test(ID string, City String, Zip String, Flag int) 
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ;
>
> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "./data.csv" OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test;
> ```

3. For each ID with Flag=0, we want to pair it with another ID with Flag=1 but with the same City - Zip. If one cannot find another paired ID with Flag=1 and matched City - Zip, we just delete that record.

Here is the Expected result:

> ```
> ID,City,Zip,Flag
> 1,A,95126,0
> 2,A,95126,1
> 4,B,95124,0
> 5,B,95124,1
> 7,C,95127,1
> 8,C,95127,0
> ```

Any valuable tips how to do this pairing in Hive or Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
select t2.*
FROM
test t1 INNER JOIN test t2
ON t1.City != t2.City
AND t1.Zip != t2.Zip
AND t1.Flag != t2.Flag
AND t1.ID<t2.ID
```

Comment: This won't work, since  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins

> Only equality joins, outer joins, and left semi joins are supported in
> Hive. Hive does not support join conditions that are not equality
> conditions as it is very difficult to express such conditions as a
> map/reduce job.